# Construct DQL by multiple Q filter

Tags: python, django

I have class `AppUser` and `AppUserGroup`

and each `AppUser` has one type and `AppUserGroup` has multiple types

```
class AppUser(BaseModel):
    user_type = m.ForeignKey('UserType', on_delete=m.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,default=1)

class AppUserGroup(BaseModel):
    user_types = m.ManyToManyField('UserType',blank=True)
```

Now I want to fetch the `AppUser` which has the type which `AppUserGroup` has , like this below `fetch_users`

```
class AppUserGroup(BaseModel):
    user_types = m.ManyToManyField('UserType',blank=True)
    def fetch_users(self):
        app_users = []
        for user_type in self.user_types:
            temp = AppUser.objects.filter(type=user_type)
            app_users.append(temp)
```

However it's wrong way , because `app_users` are not the list of AppUser.

And I call `AppUser.objects.filter` many times.

I want to call db more simply  such as

```
AppUser.objects.filter(Q(type=user_types[0] | Q(type=user_types[1] | ... ))
```

How can I construct this query??

Comment: Why don't you use `AppUser.objects.filter(user_type__in=self.user_types)`?

Comment: That' looks nice but , there comes error `'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`

Comment: try: `AppUser.objects.filter(user_type__in=self.user_types.all())`

Comment: I always forget about `.all()` Thanks @BartoszStasiak)

Comment: thank you two!! it works.　my problem is solved